# How to apply a javax custom validation on inner pojo class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, validation, pojo

I've Pojo class and custom validation like below:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Conditional(selected = "action", values = {"submit"}, required = {"data"})
public class MainDTO {

  @Size(max = 20, message = "Action should not exceed 20 characters")
  private String action;

  @Valid
  private InnerClass data;

  public static class InnerClass {
   @NotNull
   private List<String> name;
  }

}
```

I created custom validators like below.

```
@Repeatable(Conditionals.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {ConditionalValidator.class})
public @interface Conditional {

    String message() default "This field is required.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String selected();
    String[] required();
    String[] values();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Conditionals {
    Conditional[] value();
}

public class ConditionalValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Conditional, Object> {

    private String selected;
    private String[] required;
    private String message;
    private String[] values;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Conditional requiredIfChecked) {
        selected = requiredIfChecked.selected();
        required = requiredIfChecked.required();
        message = requiredIfChecked.message();
        values = requiredIfChecked.values();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object objectToValidate, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Boolean valid = true;
        try {
            Object actualValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(objectToValidate, selected);
            if (Arrays.asList(values).contains(actualValue)) {
                for (String propName : required) {
                    Object requiredValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(objectToValidate, propName);
                    valid = requiredValue != null && !isEmpty(requiredValue);
                    System.out.println("value: " + "" + requiredValue);
                    if (!valid) {
                        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message).addPropertyNode(propName).addConstraintViolation();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Accessor method is not available for class : {}, exception : {}"+ objectToValidate.getClass().getName()+ e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("Field or method is not present on class : {}, exception : {}"+ objectToValidate.getClass().getName()+ e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            System.out.println("An exception occurred while accessing class : {}, exception : {}"+objectToValidate.getClass().getName()+ e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

When I tested action as "submit" and data as null the it is working fine. Like below:

```
  public class MainDTOTest {   

    private Validator validator;

    private MainDTO dto;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

        dto = new MainDTO();
        dto.setData(null);
    }


    @Test
    public void ShouldFailOnMissingFieldsForSubmit() {
        dto.setAction("submit");
        Set<ConstraintViolation<MainDTO>> violations = validator.validate(dto);
        assertEquals(1, violations.size());
    }
}
```

But if I pass action as "save" and data as empty object instead of null then my custom validator is not working for inner class. It is still checking the inner class validation and failing the below test case.

```
public class MainDTOTest {

    private Validator validator;

    private MainDTO dto;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

        dto = new MainDTO();
        dto.setData(new MainDTO.InnerClass());
    }

    @Test
    public void ShouldNotFailOnMissingFieldsForSave() {
        dto.setAction("save");
        Set<ConstraintViolation<PartnerListingRequestDto>> violations = 
        validator.validate(dto);
        assertEquals(0, violations.size());
    }
}
```

All are having setters and getters of it's own. I'm not sure why my validator is not working on for me. Can someone please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your custom validator?

Comment: yes, I debugged it.

Comment: And? What was the result? You do realize that the `@NotNull` constraint on `InnerClass.name` is still being applied in your test, right? BTW it seems your custom validator has a logical error: you're overwriting the `valid` variable for each required property when you should be ANDing it with the result of the previous loop, otherwise the validator will only really be checking the last `required` property